# Is it viable to buy AP items with Shen?

Tags: league-of-legends

Since Shen's skills scale with AP and very well for that matter I'm surprised that nearly no one buys AP items for him. What is the reason for that? There are a lot of semi-defensive ap items or ap items with health and armor.

Comment: It's a blast to go into AI games and buy soulstealer on Shen. The shield is HUGE!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Somewhat viable to a certain extent, but not to the extent of getting [Rabadons](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rabadon%27s_Deathcap), for instance.
He gets so much more from stacking HP and resistances, since he is, in essence, a damage-soaking tank.
His kit (a shield, a taunt and a global shield-teleport) make it a must to build tanky.

Pro-tip though:  (This is not for Shen jungle, but for Shen Top.) Build a [rylai's crystal scepter](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rylai's_Crystal_Scepter) 
if you get ahead, which you should, since you are Shen after all.  That bonus AP and Health are great for Shen, and the 35% slow on Vorpal Blade is just 
too much.  That slow + taunt and you'll shut-down the enemy carries every time.

I suppose you *could* get things like [zhonya's](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Zhonya's_Hourglass), [abyssal](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Abyssal_Scepter) or 
even [DFG](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Deathfire_Grasp) but those would be tremendously **not cost-effective** on Shen.

I think it's viable, but it ends at Rylai's and masteries 9/21/0 going for the MPen.

Comment: I see that's what I thought but I wanted a pro tip.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind too:  Warmogs is just too good in it's current state. Don't sacrifice rushing the mogs to get a rylais. mogs first.

Comment: well i can't remember the last time i built mogs with shen. is it that viable? i did fine without it so far.

Comment: @AdamArold Warmogs in its current state (Thresh patch) is the strongest item in the game.  With the focus right now being on armor/MR shred, (i.e. most AD bruisers getting black cleaver) the best way to mitigate this is by stacking Health.

Comment: Oh I see. I'll try that out. Should I use my scaling health seals instead of the armor ones? I usually play top solo.

Comment: No. Unless you have a ton of rune pages, and you are playing vs something like: vlad, rumble or cho... etc AP tops.  Otherwise, flat armor yellows, scaling MR blues, ARPen marks and Quints are up to you. (I use MS+).

Comment: I always use MS runes on melee champs

Comment: I was trying out this idea of yours and in 5 games with full/semi-full AP Shen i was doing very good in terms of protecting my carries, as well as completely murdering their carry.